# Join tables with different ID

Tags: sql, join

I want to join table `order` with table `invoice` so I get the `ord_ref` and `fah_nr` merged in the same resultset. Can someone help me with the query?

Table Order

```
ord_nr  ord_dept    ord_date    ord_customer    ord_anlegg  ord_ref
17264          7    2005-11-16  52815           2005        55
18132          7    2008-08-30  58087           2008        527
```

Table Invoice

```
fah_nr  fah_customer    fah_ordre   fah_anlegg  fah_avdeling
68903      52815        17264       2005        7
69616      53796        18132       2008        7
```

Output

```
Ord_nr   fah_ordre      fah_anlegg  fah_nr    ord_ref
17264    17264          2005        68903      55 
18132    18132          2008        69616      527
```

Comment: A simple join. What have you tried?

Comment: What is the error you get? How does your query look like?

Comment: Please tag the database that you are using

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirement correctly then you may looking for simple join

```
SELECT o.Ord_nr,i.fah_ordre,fah_anlegg,fah_nr,ord_ref
FROM [Order] o
INNER JOIN Invoice i ON o.ord_nr = i.fah_ordre
```

Comment: Note that ORDER is a reserved key word in SQL and so is a very bad name for a table.  That said, it can be used but requires escaping; this answer uses `[Order]` which is MS SQL Server compatible.  Other SQL dialects may differ, such as `´Order´` or `"Order"`

Comment: @MatBailie, and ANSI SQL has double quotes, e.g. `"order"`. MS SQL Server supports that as well.

Comment: Agree with @jarlh MS SQL Server supports that as well -Thanks Jarlh

Comment: The point, however, is that the OP doesn't state SQL Server, and `[]` isn't supported by other dialects.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a pretty simple join. Simply select the values you want, then do a left join or an inner join

Here's an example with INNER JOIN

```
SELECT
   Order.ord_nr AS ord_nr,
   Invoice.fah_ordre AS fah_ordre,
   Invoice.fah_anlegg AS fah_anlegg,
   Invoice.fah_nr AS fah_nr,
   Order.ord_ref AS ord_ref
FROM
   Order
INNER JOIN
   Invoice
ON
   Order.ord_nr = Invoice.fah_ordre
```

Here's an example with LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT
   Order.ord_nr AS ord_nr,
   Invoice.fah_ordre AS fah_ordre,
   Invoice.fah_anlegg AS fah_anlegg,
   Invoice.fah_nr AS fah_nr,
   Order.ord_ref AS ord_ref
FROM
   Order
LEFT JOIN
   Invoice
ON
   Order.ord_nr = Invoice.fah_ordre
```

The difference in the two, is that if a record only exist in one of the tables, then the LEFT JOIN will still give you a result, but the INNER JOIN will not.

(Edited, and removed the old implicit join that's deprecated)

Comment: Don't encourage people to use that old, implicit join syntax. Learn them to do explicit joins from the beginning.

Comment: @jarlh You're right of course, I edited my example and removed the deprecated example.